# When working with numbers of order e-325 'decimal' python module returns '0'

Tags: python, precision

i'm trying implement a function that is expressed as a power series.
It is of the form:
[image: formula]

The problem is related to the terms t_min and t_max on the numerator: when s becomes large, both terms start giving me values of order e-324 and then when it should be e-325 python returns the value 0.
I know that it is related to the maximum precision of python and for this reason I've tried to use the 'decimal' module but it doesn't work. For example if I try something like:

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext

getcontext().prec = 400  
a = Decimal(10**(-325))
b = Decimal(10**(-325))
```

the sum returns:

```
a+b

Decimal('0')
```

Comment: The fact that you’re supplying the decimal value as `10**(-325)` already bounds you to the precision of floats. You need to initialize `Decimal` with a string or safe numeric literal, and do all your computation using operations on the `Decimal` instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`10**(-325)` is a normal double that is used to init a `Decimal`, so `a` and `b` are both `Decimal('0')`

you have to construct the Decimals

```py
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
getcontext().prec = 400

a = Decimal(10)**Decimal(-325)
b = Decimal(10)**Decimal(-325)
```

now `a+b` results in `Decimal('2E-325')`